# How to define a command that returns its argument as a superscript?

Tags: macros

How can I write the following code more concisely, without an ifcase statement? Please assume the command will only be called with integer arguments between 1 and 8, inclusive. Sorry for asking such a basic question---I'm new to macros.

```
\renewcommand{\@fnsymbol}[1]{\ifcase#1\or ^0 \or ^1\or ^2\or
                 ^3\or ^4\or ^5\or ^6\or ^7 \or ^8 \fi\relax}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `\newcommand{\mysuperscript}[1]{$^{#1}$}`? Do you plan on using this in text mode or in math mode?

Comment: LaTeX provides `\textsuperscript{<stuff>}` which "returns its argument as a superscript."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It might be helpful if you included some details as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish as there might be an easier way to do what you want.  Also, for the way you have specd it, what do you want to happen if the parameter is not a single digit?

Comment: Thanks, here's some context: I'm using a .cls file that defines a custom footer symbol. I don't like those footer symbols though, so I'm redefining the command (`@fnsymbol`) that generates the footer symbols. My command appears above, in the question. It works, but seems ridiculous to use "ifcase", just to write a command that returns its argument as a superscript. So I'm looking for a better way to duplicate the functionality of the above command.

Comment: When I replace the above command with `\renewcommand{\@fnsymbol}[1]{$^{#1}$}`, I get the error message
    ! Missing } inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                }
    l.126 to an output.\footnote{
                             %

Comment: How about including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) which would provide even more context to your current discussion?

Comment: @Jeff From the definition you have in the question, it seems that the class is assuming `\@fnsymbol` is used in math mode. Thus something like `\renewcommand{\@fnsymbol}[1]{^{#1}}` (no `$`) will work. However, as others have said it would be useful to see a demo: this is rather odd (`\@fnsymbol` is not normally in math mode).

Comment: Usually the superscript position is already managed by `\footnote`, so it may be that `\let\@fnsymbol\@arabic` is what you're looking for. What's precisely in the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\let\@fnsymbol^
```

Is probably as concise as you could get as an answer to the question, although given the command name you used, you need a bit more as it needs to work with count registers not just literal digits `\@fnsymbol{33}` would work but not `\@fnsymbol\c@footnote` and it needs to work out of math mode so you need

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{\ensuremath{^{\number#1}}}
```

But `\textsuperscript` is a better option as it uses the text fonts not the math ones.